Website's indexing is good, but impressions have dropped significantly in Google Search Console
I manage a website that has been performing well in terms of search engine indexing for quite some time. However, recently I've noticed a significant drop in impressions in Google Search Console. Here are some details:
The website has a steady flow of new content and has been regularly updated.
The indexing status shows that most of our pages are indexed without any errors.
We haven't made any major changes to the site structure or content recently.
Our SEO practices have been consistent, focusing on relevant keywords and good quality content.
We have checked for any manual actions or penalties in Google Search Console, and there are none reported.
Despite these efforts, our impressions in search results have declined sharply over the past few weeks. What could be some potential reasons for this drop in impressions, and what steps can we take to diagnose and address the issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!


First look at what specific keywords have lost traffic, and whether they have fallen in the rankings. A drop by a single position can really effect the clicks you get on a popular term.  Your graph doesn't show which keywords or how many keywords are getting you traffic, so not much can bee seen from that alone.  If all your keywords have dropped, that suggests something more algorithmic.

Hi Richard, all keywords have dropped where as are fixing everything comming from google like page speed, meta data, schema etc. I am ready to restart its really pain full to see hard work gone wate :(
